# jquery hide 2 div in entire page

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I want to hide all 2nd div inside another div

```
     <div class="inner">
       <div class="content"></div>
       **<div class="content"></div>**   // this show get hidden
    </div>

     <div class="inner">
       <div class="content"></div>
       **<div class="content"></div**>   // this should get hidden
    </div>
```

I have tried this:

```
           $($('.inner').children()[12]).hide();
```

but it only hides one element,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without :nthchild selector:

```
$('.inner').each(function()
{
   $(this).find('.content').eq(1).hide(); 
});​
```

with :nthchild:

```
$(".inner div:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nth-child selector from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to easily accomplish this.

```
$(".inner div:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.inner div:nth-child(2)').hide()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TmWzd/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".content").next().hide(); will do the Job.
```

OR

```
$(".inner").find(".content").eq(1).hide();
```